# How to automatically post a message with the discount on the site?

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I have a store with Commerce 2 and Drupal 8.

In my store I created a reminder of 20% on the whole site.

I want a message to be posted on my site with the conditions, the percentage, the end date and the description of the discount.

A bit like this :

[image]

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool for general messages like this, because every site will construct its front-end differently. If this is only an occasional matter, you'd be best just creating the content manually. If it's going to happen with some regularity, you may just be best using custom code to define a template that can load a promotion entity and fill in the offer details from its fields.

Comment: I created a discounted view. Can not display the amount of the discount, there is nothing in the view. How to do ?

Comment: My recommendation was for custom code b/c I wasn't sure how integrated into Views all the parameters of a promotion are. How in control of the theme layer are you?

Comment: I finally found a solution using the description field of the discount in my view.